# Cannot break while loop in C++

Tags: c++

I created a program, that calculates volume of prism and area of rectangle.
But I want user to decide how how long he wants to work with this programm:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool run = true;
    while(run = true){
        double len,width,area,volume,height;
        char check;
        cout << "Please, enter length,width and height of a prism(rectangular)!";
        cin >> len >> width >> height;
        area = width*len;
        volume = area*height;
        cout << "The area of rectangle is equal to: " << area << "\n" << "The volume of rectangular prism is equal to: " << volume << "\n";
        cout << "Do you want to try again?(y/n)\n";
        cin >> check;
        while(check != 'y'|| check != 'n'){
            cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
            cin >> check;
        }
        if(check == 'n'){
            run = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the first part everything works fine, but I cannot get out of this loop:

```
while(check != 'y'|| check != 'n'){
                cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
                cin >> check;
            }
```

Where did I do the mistake and how can I fix it?

Comment: if you read your while-condition out loud, you'll find your logic error --> no matter what you enter, it always evaluates as true.

Comment: I just realised it is a nested meme loop. Creating a function, running it first time on default and then having a switch case wouldn't be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did 2 mistakes :

1 : `while(run = true){` is an assignement. Use `==` to compare

2:     `while(check != 'y'|| check != 'n'){`

So if `check` is different than y (lets say `check = 'n'`), you will continue your loop. Use `&&` instead

Here is a working example :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        double len, width, area, volume, height;
        char check;
        cout << "Please, enter length,width and height of a prism(rectangular)!";
        cin >> len >> width >> height;
        area = width*len;
        volume = area*height;
        cout << "The area of rectangle is equal to: " << area << "\n" << "The volume of rectangular prism is equal to: " << volume << "\n";
        cout << "Do you want to try again?\n";
        do {
            cout << "Please enter y or n\n"; cin >> check;
            cin.clear();
        } while (check != 'y' && check !='n');

        if (check == 'n') {
            run = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: cout messages are repeating without adding cin.clear(); and consider removing one of those  cout << "Do you want to try again?(y/n)\n"; , cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";

Comment: @AESTHETICS This is not relevant to his question

Comment: It is related to aesthetics of the question. Output of the program might not be clear and by that answer might be confusing.

Comment: @AESTHETICS thus your username haha

Comment: For better understanding you can also use (!(check == 'y' || check =='n')) for the while statement

Answer (score 7):

`while (run = true)` is always `true`, and it has the side effect of setting `run` to `true`.

Did you want `==`? Didn't your compiler warn you of this? Better still, drop the tautology `run == true` and write `while (run)`.

Then fix the other conditional to `while (check != 'y'&& check != 'n')`. Think about this: `check != 'y'|| check != 'n'` is *always* `true` (if `check` is `y`, say, then it's therefore not `n`). *That* logic error is extremely common.

Finally, I'm not sure what you really achieve with the introduction and therefore the maintenance of `run`. Why not replace it with `while (true)`, and write `return 0;` in place of `break`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it should be done:

```
do {
    cout << "Do you want to try again?(y/n)\n"; cin >> check;
    cin.clear();
} while (check != 'y' && check !='n');
```

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool run = true;
    while (run) {
        double len, width, area, volume, height;
        char check;
        cout << "Please, enter length,width and height of a prism(rectangular)!";
        cin >> len >> width >> height;
        area = width*len;
        volume = area*height;
        cout << "The area of rectangle is equal to: " << area << "\n" << "The volume of rectangular prism is equal to: " << volume << "\n";
        do {
            cout << "Do you want to try again?(y/n)\n"; cin >> check;
            cin.clear();
        } while (check != 'y' && check !='n');

        if (check == 'n') {
            run = false;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It only fixes half the issues: the program still runs for ever.

Comment: What do you think `while(run = true){` does?

Answer (score 1):

```
check != 'y' || check != 'n'
```

This is always true, since check cannot equal to 'y' and 'n' at the same time. You should change it to

```
check != 'y' && check != 'n'
```

By the way, you wrote at the outer loop

```
while (run = true)
```

This will result in run getting assigned to true at the begining of each outer loop and since this expression also returns true, you end up in a dead loop. This should be changed to

```
while (run == true)
```

Enabling compiler warning and possibly -Werror will help avoid such problem. And of course for bool variables you can just write `while (run)`.

Comment: Could I suggest you use `while (run)` instead of `while (run == true)`? Then there's no confusion about whether it's `=` or `==`, and I think it looks a bit neater.

Answer (score 1):

For starters the variable `run` in this loop

```
bool run = true;
while(run = true){
    // ...
    if(check == 'n'){
        run = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

is redundant. In fact the loop does not depend on the variable `run`. The loop stops its iteration due to the `break` statement in the if statement

```
    if(check == 'n'){
        run = false;
        break;
    }
```

independent on whether the Boolean literal `true` will be assigned to the variable as it is done in the condition of the while statement (it seems you mean comparison `run == true` instead of the assignment)

```
while(run = true){
```

or the Boolean literal `false` will be assigned to the variable as it is done in the if statement

```
    if(check == 'n'){
        run = false;
        break;
    }
```

In fact you have an infinite loop that can be stopped only by the break statement.

So just remove the variable and write the loop the following way

```
while( true ){
    // ...
    if(check == 'n'){
        break;
    }
}
```

As for the second loop

```
    while(check != 'y'|| check != 'n'){
        cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
        cin >> check;
    }
```

then its condition will always yield true because neither character can be simultaneously equal to `'y'` and to `'n'`.

So a valid condition should look like

```
    while(check != 'y' && check != 'n'){
        cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
        cin >> check;
    }
```

Or you could make it even more readable the following way

```
    while( not ( check == 'y' || check == 'n' ) ){
        cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
        cin >> check;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
bool run = true;
while(run == true){
    double len,width,area,volume,height;
    char check;
    cout << "Please, enter length,width and height of a prism(rectangular)!";
    cin >> len >> width >> height;
    area = width*len;
    volume = area*height;
    cout << "The area of rectangle is equal to: " << area << "\n" << "The volume of rectangular prism is equal to: " << volume << "\n";
    cout << "Do you want to try again?(y/n)\n";
    cin >> check;
    while(check != 'y' && check != 'n'){
        cout <<"Please enter y or n\n";
        cin >> check;
    }
    if(check == 'n'){
            run = false;
            break;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You must change the `=` sign in the first loop for `==` and also need `&&`instead of `||`in the other while loop.

Answer (score -1):

Try having `check` as a `string` instead of a `char`.

Comment: This is about as useful as a trap door in a canoe.

Comment: Hm, why? @Bathsheba